# Routing between ASP.NET Core web application and Razor Class Library projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created a project ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC and it works fine. In the same solution, I added 3 (or more) projects "Razor Class Library". Each such project has a controller. How do I configure routing so that I can access the controller methods of these projects?

My solution looks like this:

```
MyProject.Shop (Razor Class Library)
|_ Controllers
    |_ HomeController.cs
MyProject.Books (Razor Class Library)
|_ Controllers
    |_ HomeController.cs
MyProject.Web (main ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC project)
|_ Controllers
    |_ HomeControlles.cs
```

Currently, routing works perfectly only within one main project. You can't access the controller in Myproject.Book etc. Maybe you need to configure Application Parts, but how do I do this in my case?

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
  endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "areas",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
});
```

Comment: do you specify the area in the <a></a> tag also?

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you need to do in order to make this work for each library, so let's go over each one, using your `Shop` library as an example, and this is for ASP.NET Core 3.1.

#### Add a reference to your Razor class library from your `Web` project

Right-click the `Dependencies` folder of your `Web` project, select `Add Project Reference...`, check the box next to `Shop` and click `OK`.

#### Make sure your controllers and views folders are under an `Areas/AreaName/` folder

In your case, this means your controllers and views should be under an `Areas/Shop` folder, like this:

[image: Razor class library folder structure]

#### Decorate the controllers in your library with an `AreaAttribute`

For your `Shop` project, this means doing the following for your `Shop` project's `HomeController` class:

```
[Area("shop")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

#### Copy `_ViewStart.cshtml` to your `Shop` project

From your `Web` project, copy `Views/_ViewStart.cshtml` to your `Shop` project's `Areas/Shop/Views` folder. It should look like this:

[image: shop-view-start-folder-placement]

This is so your layout is consistent between your `Web` and `Shop` projects.

#### Update your routing configuration in your `Web` project to include routing for the area

In this example, the routes are configured in your `Web` project's `Startup.cs` like so:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        name: "shop-default", 
        areaName: "shop", 
        pattern: "shop/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Now, launching your application and going to the default URL should show you the normal home page, but navigating to `/shop` will show you whatever you have in your `Views/Shop/Index.cshtml` view.

From doing the above, I see the home page:

[image: home-page]

and can also navigate to the shop:

[image: shop-page]

...and I'm apparently hungry and wanting icecream.

Naturally, you'll need to go through the same kind of process for your `Books` library.

Answer (score 3):

The structure of the whole solution is below:

[image]

> Razor Class Library

**Configuration**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RazorLangVersion>3.0</RazorLangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures" Version="2.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Codes of Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [Area("books")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public string Index()
        {
            return "Books Home Index";
        }
    }
}
```

> Main MVC project

**Codes of Startup.cs in ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC project**

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "areas",
              pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });
```

**Add `Project Reference...`**

[image]

### Test

[image]