# MVC in a Core Library

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I built this project and it contained a simple MVC type structure to help with debugging information.  Now the company wants to use it in other applications like a Library
The best way, I can describe it is

My Project **Debugger** Is a single controller with multiple end-points that render views (pretty basic), written in C#.

What I want is when another project wants to include my debugging, they would:

1. Add **Debugger** as a reference using NuGet.
2. Then in Start.cs the developer would use IApplicationBuilder.UseDebugger(IConfiguration, OtherInformation) or IServiceCollection.UseDebugger(IConfiguration, OtherInformation) and **Debugger** extension would do the rest like registering routes, building what it needs for dependency injection.

What I cannot figure out is what project type to use, I built it using .NET Core Web Application 3.1, but I do not think it is that.  I also tried a .Net Standard class Library but I could not get a reference to controller to render views.

So to summarize, I want to convert part of my project to a library to allow for distribution to other applications.

A link to an example project would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [Razor Class Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).

> Razor views, pages, controllers, page models, Razor components, View components, and data models can be built into a Razor class library (RCL). The RCL can be packaged and reused. Applications can include the RCL and override the views and pages it contains. When a view, partial view, or Razor Page is found in both the web app and the RCL, the Razor markup (.cshtml file) in the web app takes precedence.

Edit: I just realised I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63953254/729541) about setting up a Razor Class Library last month, so that will give you a starting point, too.